# Need to remove a hierarchy from my out in mdx and also mirror the SSMS output in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ssms, mdx

very very new to mdx and have been generating my queries by setting up the query in an Excel Pivot table and then exporting the query to a txt doc.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
    Hierarchize(DrilldownMember({{DrilldownLevel({[Date].[Fiscal].[All].Children},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}},
                                                 {[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2024],[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2023],
                                                 [Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2022]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS))
                                            
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME,
        [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].[FiscalPeriodType],[Date].[Fiscal].[Period].[FiscalYear],[Date].[Fiscal].[Period].[IsLatestData] ON COLUMNS , 
        
    NON EMPTY CrossJoin(Hierarchize(DrilldownMember({{DrilldownLevel({[Account].[CoA].Children},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}},
        {[Account].[CoA].&[14432]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)),
        
        Hierarchize({[Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].AllMembers})) 
        
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME,
        [Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].[Parent Display Order],
        [Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].[Scenario Parent Description],[Account].[CoA].[AccountOrderKey],
        [Account].[CoA].[CoA],[Account].[CoA].[CustomMemberFormula],[Account].[CoA].[Display Format String Billion],
        [Account].[CoA].[Display Format String Million],[Account].[CoA].[Display Format String Thousand],
        [Account].[CoA].[Display Format String Unit],[Account].[CoA].[IsVarianceInPoint],[Account].[CoA].[VarianceFlipSign] ON ROWS  
        
    FROM (SELECT ({[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2024]}) ON COLUMNS , 
    ({[Account].[CoA].&[14436], [Account].[CoA].&[14433]},{[Scenario].[Scenario].[Prior Year], [Scenario].[Scenario].[Actuals]}) ON ROWS

FROM [CUBE])

WHERE ([Organization].[Management].[All],[Organization].[ServiceLine].[All],[PeriodType].[PeriodType].&[5],[Measures].[Local]) 

CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

I managed to remove `All` columns by changing `ALLMEMBERS` to `Children` where appropriate. The issue when running it in SSMS is that I can't remove the `Billing` field which is a level above `Bills Issued` and `Cash Collected`. I also can't work out how to remove `2024` which sits above all the periods given in the table below. The output in SSMS looks like this (some numbers replaced with randomly generated):

|  |  | 2024 | FY24 OpeningBal | FY24 July | FY24 August | FY24 September | FY24 October | FY24 November | FY24 December | FY24 January | FY24 February | FY24 March | FY24 April | FY24 May | FY24 June | FY24 Adjustment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Billings | Actuals | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E+00 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 |
| Billings | Prior Year | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E+00 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 | 1.00E-05 |
| Bills Issued | Actuals | 0.571759 | (null) | 0.644204 | 0.342599 | 0.565033 | 0.049328 | 0.741076 | 0.767904 | 0.456827 | 0.086739 | 0.895016 | 0.16319 | 0.893175 | 0.974494 | 0.158187 |
| Bills Issued | Prior Year | 0.21984 | (null) | 0.708076 | 0.308315 | 0.995772 | 0.609942 | 0.085712 | 0.387499 | 0.6073 | 0.686889 | 0.789851 | 0.303484 | 0.867292 | 0.855121 | 0.636389 |
| Cash Collected | Actuals | 0.397955 | (null) | 0.928985 | 0.766025 | 0.415052 | 0.191884 | 0.069434 | 0.292659 | 0.886183 | 0.095258 | 0.363058 | 0.21286 | 0.926778 | 0.758365 | 0.779428 |
| Cash Collected | Prior Year | 0.334408 | (null) | 0.072637 | 0.562313 | 0.610455 | 0.247378 | 0.994229 | 0.747458 | 0.896372 | 0.898893 | 0.479051 | 0.923123 | 0.54981 | 0.97782 | 0.940315 |

Then when I use the same query in Python so I can use the data for some data visualization I have a table that looks nothing like the one in SSMS! The code I am using is:

```
with Pyadomd(conn) as conn:
    with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
        yoy_table = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=[i.name for i in cur.description])
```

Giving the following DataFrame which is not what I want at all. I want it to reflect the same output as SSMS with the `Billing` and `2024` levels removed. Again, random numbers generated:

| [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[AccountOrderKey] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[CoA] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[CustomMemberFormula] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[Display Format String Billion] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[Display Format String Million] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[Display Format String Thousand] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[Display Format String Unit] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[IsVarianceInPoint] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 01].[VarianceFlipSign] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[AccountOrderKey] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[CoA] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[CustomMemberFormula] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[Display Format String Billion] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[Display Format String Million] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[Display Format String Thousand] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[Display Format String Unit] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[IsVarianceInPoint] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 02].[VarianceFlipSign] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[AccountOrderKey] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[CoA] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[CustomMemberFormula] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[Display Format String Billion] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[Display Format String Million] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[Display Format String Thousand] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[Display Format String Unit] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[IsVarianceInPoint] | [Account].[CoA].[Level 03].[VarianceFlipSign] | [Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].[PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].[HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME] | [Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].[Parent Display Order] | [Scenario].[Scenario].[Scenario Parent].[Scenario Parent Description] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2024] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024000] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024001] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024002] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024003] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024004] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024005] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024006] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024007] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024008] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024009] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024010] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024011] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024012] | [Date].[Fiscal].[Period].&[2024998] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | [Account].[CoA] | 4487 |  | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14392] | [Account].[CoA] | 17 | StatisticalAccounts | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | [Scenario].[Scenario] | 10 | Actuals | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 |
|  | [Account].[CoA] | 4487 |  | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14392] | [Account].[CoA] | 17 | StatisticalAccounts | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | [Scenario].[Scenario] | 50 | Prior Year | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 | 1e-05 |
|  | [Account].[CoA] | 4487 |  | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14392] | [Account].[CoA] | 17 | StatisticalAccounts | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14432] | [Account].[CoA] | 1 | Billings |  | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 |  | [Scenario].[Scenario] | 10 | Actuals | 2405654600658.94 | nan | 325801981374.8 | 654084986749.85 | 992609332674.99 | 1415977517569.43 | 1881457636457.15 | 2354597431066.9 | 2405654600658.94 | 2405654600658.94 | 2405654600658.94 | 2405654600658.94 | 2405654600658.94 | 2405654600658.94 | 2405654600658.94 |
|  | [Account].[CoA] | 4487 |  | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14392] | [Account].[CoA] | 17 | StatisticalAccounts | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14432] | [Account].[CoA] | 1 | Billings |  | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 |  | [Scenario].[Scenario] | 50 | Prior Year | 4847109487854.47 | nan | 361776526533.39 | 697446208884.35 | 1039075952282.75 | 1360198428809.48 | 1796509307733.14 | 2484183407724.12 | 2797502022044.86 | 3063373428169.33 | 3474984450971.24 | 3866716314945.89 | 4339590828278.79 | 4847109487854.47 | 4847109487854.47 |
|  | [Account].[CoA] | 4487 |  | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14392] | [Account].[CoA] | 17 | StatisticalAccounts | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14432] | [Account].[CoA] | 3 | Billings |  | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 |  | [Scenario].[Scenario] | 10 | Actuals | 2432820164876.82 | nan | 432062213727.32 | 824116279516.18 | 1167631245677.22 | 1581419042955.97 | 1986055270473.5 | 2400827822041.97 | 2432820164876.82 | 2432820164876.82 | 2432820164876.82 | 2432820164876.82 | 2432820164876.82 | 2432820164876.82 | 2432820164876.82 |
|  | [Account].[CoA] | 4487 |  | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14392] | [Account].[CoA] | 17 | StatisticalAccounts | 1e-05 | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 | [Account].[CoA].&[14432] | [Account].[CoA] | 3 | Billings |  | #,0,,,.0;(#,0,,,.0);0; | #,0,,.0;(#,0,,.0);0; | #,0,;(#,0,);0; | #,0;(#,0);0; | 0 | 0 |  | [Scenario].[Scenario] | 50 | Prior Year | 4708345088279.18 | nan | 393235202258 | 749663471237.72 | 1136615456661.85 | 1488673181385.13 | 1779096047902.8 | 2218244064574.85 | 2694355903413.32 | 3084398990937.76 | 3471719057050.8 | 3883452909922.2 | 4283634695439.38 | 4708345088279.18 | 4708345088279.18 |

Any help greatly appreciated!